# Does evasion from multiple sources via multiclassing stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, multi-classing, rogue

I'm making a rogue/monk ninja character for a campaign a friend is running and at latter levels I will have taken evasion from both the rogue and the monk. Would evasion take effect twice on a failed save for 1/4 of the original damage?

Comment: Please note which system you’re playing with the appropriate tag on your question. Without that, we cannot answer this question, as different systems may have different rules.

Comment: It looks like this is your first time on the site, so Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please take a look at [this nifty tour of the site](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) so you can see what's up, and maybe look at the [help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any more questions. You can also find these on the navigation menu at the top of the page where it says "help". As @KRyan points out, we can't really tell what system you are using in your question. It looks like maybe D&D 3.5e? Please tell us so we can answer.

Comment: The system is 5e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there are a lot of ways in which you can take 1/4 damage from *fireball*s, this isn't one of them.

The text of Evasion is identical for both the Rogue and the Monk:

> When you are subjected
>   to an effect that allows you to make a Dexterity saving
>   throw to take only half damage, you instead take no
>   damage if you succeed on the saving throw, and only half
>   damage if you fail.

So if you have Evasion twice, you will take no damage if you succeed on the saving throw, and half damage if you fail.

Comment: You could add "or a magical items, or spells that resist elemental damage"  after barbarian levels for a more complete answer ... though I appreciate that items are DM controlled and spells are likely controlled by other characters.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I shouldn't really have put that bit in, as it's not part of the answer to the question asked - I figured I could get away with it but from your reaction maybe it was subverting the question a bit too much.